# if two column values are equal then create 3rd column which has True and False values in Python

Tags: python, excel, logic, boolean-logic

I want to get 3rd column which would have boolean values i.e. True and False,
say I have column A which has numeric value and column B which also has some numeric value, I need to compare them whether they're equal, so If they're equal then there will be TRUE value in 3rd column, else False in python data frame

**Input:**

[image]

**Output Required**

[image]

Comment: You mean like `df['C'] = (df['A']==df['B'])`?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['3rd Column']=df['A']==df['B']

df:

  A    B    Third Column
 10    20   FALSE
 20    10   FALSE
 30    30   TRUE
 50    40   FALSE
 80    60   FALSE`
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.